# Undefined index warning on PDO::fetchAll index

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, indexing, undefined

I'm having an awful time trying to track down the cause of this since there are so many different potential causes for an "Undefined Index" warning.

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in D:\xampp\htdocs\inc\php_main.php on line 71
```

The line `$singleresult = $result[0];` is line 71. I'm positive `$result[0]` is set, as I've verified it both with `print_r` and with an `isset` check. Am I missing something? I'm sort of hoping I just need a sanity check here. :)

```
function execute ($sql, $bindingsarray) {
    $pdostmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $pdostmt->execute($bindingsarray);
    $result = $pdostmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($result);
    if (isset($result[0]) && isset($result[1])); {
        $singleresult = $result[0];
        return $singleresult;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable is not set and you don't notice that because your `if` line is wrong:

```
if (isset($result[0]) && isset($result[1])); {
                                           ^ your problem
    $singleresult = $result[0];
    return $singleresult;
}
```

Is the same as:

```
if (isset($result[0]) && isset($result[1])) {

}
$singleresult = $result[0];
return $singleresult;
```

because of the `;` you put after your condition. Just remove it and the results should be what you expect them to be:

```
if (isset($result[0]) && isset($result[1])) {
```